# Using multiple != and || in if-statement

Tags: c++

I am still new in C++ and I am trying to make my code print "Invalid customer type" when the input(customer) received does not equal "r", "R", "b", or "B". Then it prompts the user again to enter a letter. With the code I've written, "Invalid customer type." is still printed out even when the customer == one of the letters "r", "R", "b", or "B". I have tried making the customer a char instead of string but that didn't change much.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string customer;
    do
    {
        cout << "Pleas Enter the Customer Type (R for Regular, B for Business): " << endl;
        cin >> customer;
        if ((customer != "r") || (customer != "R") || (customer != "b") || (customer != "B"))
        {
            cout << "Invalid customer type." << endl;
        }

    } while ((customer != "r") || (customer != "R") || (customer != "b") || (customer != "B"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When its `!=` you need to use `&&`. You want to exclude all those conditons not any of them.

Comment: I can guarantee that `customer` is going to be not equal to `"r"` OR it is going to be not equal to `"R"`.    So the conditions you are testing are always true.    These means, for every input, the program will output `"Invalid customer type"` and the loop will run forever.

Answer (score 3):

Use `&&` instead of `||`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string customer;
    do
    {
        cout << "Pleas Enter the Customer Type (R for Regular, B for Business): " << endl;
        cin >> customer;
        if ((customer != "r") && (customer != "R") && (customer != "b") && (customer != "B"))
        {
            cout << "Invalid customer type." << endl;
        }

    } while ((customer != "r") && (customer != "R") && (customer != "b") && (customer != "B"));
    return 0;
}
```

If we take just the first two conditions, for the sake of simplicity

```
(customer != "r") || (customer != "R")
```

One of these conditions will always be true and when using logical OR, if any subcondition evaluates to true, the whole condition evaluates to true.

We need to use logical AND so that if any subcondition is false the whole condition evaluates to false.

This is a bit confusing as you would use `||` if your conditions were testing for equality rather than inequality.

e.g.

```
if ((customer == "r") || (customer == "R") || (customer == "b") || (customer == "B"))
```

You could also refactor your code to be a bit more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

```
int main ()
{
    string customer;
    while(true)
    {
        cout << "Pleas Enter the Customer Type (R for Regular, B for Business): " << endl;
        cin >> customer;
        if ((customer == "r") || (customer == "R") || (customer == "b") || (customer == "B"))
        {
            break;
        }

        cout << "Invalid customer type." << endl;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the customer enters `r`,`R`,`b`, or`B`, then it is an input for the valid customer. That means that the condition for a valid customer will be:

`((customer == "r") || (customer == "R") || (customer == "b") || (customer == "B"))`

To check the invalidity of the customer, you will have to take the **logical not** of the above condition which will be:

`!((customer == "r") || (customer == "R") || (customer == "b") || (customer == "B"))`

This will work. However, you can apply [De Morgan's Law](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/boolean/demorgan.html) to this expression which will result:

`((customer != "r") && (customer != "R") && (customer != "b") && (customer != "B"))`